# How can we provide Jackson annotations for java 17 record class

Tags: java, json, java-17

How can we create add field level annotations for java 17 record class?

```
record Rectangle(double length, double width) { }
```

Comment: Is this a Jackson question? If yes, Jackson supports records since 2.12, here's a blog post about it: https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-2-12-most-wanted-5-5-a32c28c345b5

Comment: Petr is right. There was already a GitHub issue for it which has been closed because it was solved: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-future-ideas/issues/46.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

yes we can use field level annotations (annotation with `@Target(ElementType.FIELD)` in the defination.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
record Rectangle(
    @JsonProperty("lengthAlias") double length,
    double width) { }
```